# aws permission denied (publickey) new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, private-key

I made a new EC2 instance on AWS including a new key pair and adding SSH to the security group. Here's the output trace:

> ssh.exe : OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016 At line:1 char:4
>   + ssh <<<<  -v -i .\CHEFtutorial.pem ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazo naws.com 2> out.txt
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OpenSSH_7.1p2, ....2h  3 May 2016     :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: Connecting to
>   ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.14
>   8.153.153] port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file .\CHEFtutorial.pem type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file .\CHEFtutorial.pem-cert type -1
>
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
>   OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubun tu-4ubuntu2.1
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat
>   0x04000000 debug1: Authenticating to
>   ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22  as 'i861009'
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com 
>   none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com 
>   none
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>   SHA256:8jkpw+J1G8Lx8eamhiOYm0xTtCA
>   +ElsRgJznVyK7Rnw
>
> debug1: Host 'ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is
>   known and  matches the ECDSA host key.
>
> debug1: Found key in /c/Users/i861009/.ssh/known_hosts:2
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Trying private
>   key: .\CHEFtutorial.pem
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied
>   (publickey).

The input was `ssh -v -i .\CHEFtutorial.pem ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. For what reason would the server be rejecting the key? I have not played with any permissions information, which other answers to this question have noted as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also mention the name of the user you're doing ssh to on that server.

E.g. if the machine is an Ubuntu instance I'll have to do

ssh -v -i .\CHEFtutorial.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Try to find out the corresponding user for your machine. You can get it in AWS docs, I guess. Then just prefix **username@** before the server address.

Comment: I have already double checked the username for the system. Mine is an ubuntu instance, and I have tried both ubuntu and root as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the permission of the pem file is 400

Go the Directory where pem file exist and execute

```
sudo chmod 400 CHEFtutorial.pem
```

then execute

```
ssh -v -i CHEFtutorial.pem username@ec2-54-148-153-153.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

If it is an ubuntu servers provide `username` as `ubuntu` and for rhel or centos servers provide username as `ec2-user`.

Note:- if the owner of the pem file is root , provide the command with `sudo`

Comment: I have already ran that command. Is there a way to test and confirm that the permissions have been modified as intended?

Comment: Just go to that directory and give 'ls -l' or 'll' , it will list the file with it's permission and ownership